# Allow scraping through API google maps businesses

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am providing **scraping** service on Upwork using the API key of Google maps to get businesses places data? Can google please reply that they allow so I can show proof to upwork so I can provide a proof?

Comment: Your question was downvoted probably because it seems off-topic to people. StackOverflow is a place for code-level programming questions. Your question, in English, sounds more like a support question that should be directed to Google.

But if you elaborate on your question (tell us more) maybe it is on topic and we can help.

The first thing you should do is copy and paste the UpWork project you're working on here so we can see what they asked you to do.

The second think you should do is paste your code or a link to your code here so we can review what you've done.

Comment: I am a freelancer and am able to extract businesses data from Google maps using Google API but upwork.com is asking me for a proof that google map has allowed me to work on scrapping their data so i want google to provide me proof certificate saying that using API we are allowed to scrape so i can show to upwork and they approve my profile

Comment: Great job clarifying, be sure to move that to your post up above and you'll avoid those down votes.

I would post the exact message that UpWork is telling you. There are different ways to "prove" this. But the simplest way would be to show a Loom video (or something) that shows you accessing your Google Maps API, getting the API keys, submitting them to your application and running your application to get your output. The other way would be to review the Google Maps API Documentation for "disallowed" or "banned" activities. Their API's usually explain what it can and cannot be used for.